# How to combine sns.jointplot and sns.lmplot?

Tags: python, matplotlib, seaborn

This is my code:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib as mpl

%matplotlib inline

# Load data
datos = {'x':[1,2,3,4,5,1,2,3,4,5],
         'y':[10, 20, 25, 35, 40, 50, 40, 30, 20, 10],
         'estado':['OK', 'OK', 'OK', 'OK', 'OK', 'Parado', 'Parado', 'Parado', 'Parado', 'Parado']}
df = pd.DataFrame(datos)

# Show data
sns.jointplot(data=df, x="x", y="y", hue="estado")
sns.lmplot(data=df, x="x", y="y", hue="estado");
```

I would like to join these two plots using seaborn, how could I do it?

[image: Plots to join:]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The axes level equivalent of `sns.lmplot` is `sns.regplot`. But for some reason, `sns.regplot` doesn't support `hue` (yet).

You can simulate `hue` by explicitly looping through all values, and taking care that the same color is applied to the same values.

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns
import pandas as pd
 
datos = {'x':[1,2,3,4,5,1,2,3,4,5],
         'y':[10, 20, 25, 35, 40, 50, 40, 30, 20, 10],
         'estado':['OK', 'OK', 'OK', 'OK', 'OK', 'Parado', 'Parado', 'Parado', 'Parado', 'Parado']}
df = pd.DataFrame(datos)

pal = sns.color_palette(n_colors=2)
g = sns.jointplot(data=df, x='x', y='y', hue='estado', hue_order=['OK', 'Parado'], palette=pal)

for estado, color in zip(['OK', 'Parado'], pal):
    sns.regplot(data=df[df['estado'] == estado], x='x', y='y', color=color, truncate=False, ax=g.ax_joint)
plt.show()
```

[image: sns.jointplot with regression]